# Can one commandline argument's `type` be dependent on the value of another argument with argparse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm writing a collection of python scripts that can parse multiple input formats, but the `type` of these inputs is decided by another commandline argument. How can I make one argument affect the type of another argument?

Example demonstrating my desired behavior:

```py
import argparse

def load_single_file(filepath: str):
    ...

def load_directory(filepath: str):
    ...

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--type', choices=('single-file', 'directory'), required=True)
parser.add_argument('input', type=load_single_file if '--type' == 'single-file' else load_directory)
```

I don't want to have to post-process `parser.parse_args()` because I'm writing a large number of scripts, all which need this input style, except some of which might take their `'input'` argument differently (e.g. one might take two such arguments, one might be `input1 3 4 randomInfo input2`, or `--first input1 --second input2`, etc.) which means that I can't generally know which arguments should be parsed if I do so in post-processing:

```py
# This doesn't work:
def parse_args(parser):
    parser.add_argument('--type', choices=('single-file', 'directory'), required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    parser = load_single_file if args.type== 'single-file' else load_directory
    # Which elements of `args` should have `parser` applied to it? It's impossible to tell.
    # I cannot just specify `'input'` here too, as some scripts may want multiple or interspersed inputs.
```

It is also important to me that I can collect this behavior into a function, because I have several arguments (not just `--type`) which would affect the way to parse the data (e.g. `--filter` to filter out some data)

---

Summarizing:

- Given `--type Value`, `input` should be parsed differently depending on `Value`
- I don't want to handle this different parsing by post-processing `parse_args()`, since that will require knowledge about the arguments to the specific script that I won't have in my "library."
- I am writing a large number of closely related scripts that all need this interface, which is why I want to abstract out a general `parse_args(parser)` or similar function.

Comment: When the `type` function is executed, it does not have access to the `namespace`, so can't check the values of other arguments.  And there's no guarantee that '--type' will be given first.  Seriously revisit the post-parsing option.  Also `load_file`, and `load_dirctectory` sound like actions on a name, not simple string conversion and testing (like `int`).  Even builtin File_Type` class is better suited fir small scripts, not big ones.

Comment: A `type` function takes a string, and should return a new object to put in the `args` namespace object (or raise an error).  Most commonly used ones are `int` and `float`.  `FileType` returns an opened `file` object (not loaded), and was intended for quick input/output scripts.  It hasn't aged well, because now Python recommends opening files in an `with` context, which can close them as soon as loading is done.  `argparse` was not intended to be a do-everything tool.  It's primary purpose is parse the users input, with convenient error and helps.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm willing to do it in post-processing, but only if I can solve the issue of knowing _which_ elements of the `args` namespace object should be post-processed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `type` for this is questionable. It's harder to understand and inefficient at the least. `script --input input --help` will parse `input` using the `parse_input` function *before* `argparse` realizes that there is a `--help` and it should just print the help message and exit.

It's not *quite* as nice, but you can still get this behavior with a custom `parse_args(...)` function that adds the library flags, but also takes in the names to use `parse_input` on as a parameter. This has the added benefit of having more flexibility in error handling as well:

```py
def parse_args(parser, *names):
    parser.add_argument('--type', choices=('single-file', 'directory'), required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    parser = load_single_file if args.type == 'single-file' else load_directory
    args_dict = vars(args)

    for name in names:
        args_dict[name] = parser(args_dict[name])

    return args
```

Example usage:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('input')

args = parse_args(parser, 'input')
```

It's not *perfect* because you have to specify `'input'` in an extra location, but the code is far easier to follow; no globals or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this behavior by parsing arguments twice and setting a global:

```py
# Use for type=parse_input
def parse_input(str, parse_fn=None):
    if parse_fn is None:
        parse_fn = parse_input.parse_fn

    return parse_fn(str)

def parse_args(parser):
    def add_args(parser, required):
        parser.add_argument('--type', choices=('single-file', 'directory'), required=required)

    # No --help, because we want to get the --help for `parser` if so
    initial_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    # Any required arguments should be set to False so that we can get the message from `parser`
    add_args(initial_parser, required=False)
    first, rest = initial_parser.parse_known_args()

    # Note: if you use prefix_chars, these won't necessarily be `-h` and `--help`.
    # Use:
    # if '-' in parser.prefix_chars:
    #     p = '-'
    # else:
    #     p = parser.prefix_chars[0]
    # And:
    #   f'{p}h', f'{p}{p}help'
    if all(h not in rest for h in ('-h', '--help')):
        parse_input.parse_fn = load_single_file if first.type== 'single-file' else load_directory
    else:
        # Allow better error message if parse_fn is missing
        parse_input.parse_fn = lambda s: s

    add_args(parser, required=True)
    return parser.parse_args()
```

Usage:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('input', type=parse_input)
...

args = parse_args(parser)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what's the problem with:

```
 def parse_args():
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
      parser.add_argument('--type', choices=('single-file', 'directory'), required=True)
      parser.add_argument('input', type=load_single_file if '--type' == 'single-file' else load_directory)
      args = parser.parse_args()
      # print(args) # for debugging
      foo = load_single_file(args.input) if args.type=='single-file' else load_directory(args.input)
      args.input = foo    # if you want that result back on args
      return args
```

If you know that `input` depends on `type` while creating the `parser`, you also know that immediately after.

Knowing what your `load` functions do, might give further insight.  The expectation is that the `type` function will perform a simple conversion, or raise an error if something is wrong (`TypeError`, `ValueError` or `argparse.ArgumentTypeError`).  `argparse.FileType` is perhaps the most elaborate type callable that `argparse` developers have considered, and even that is has not aged well.  All it does is open a file, but now we are encouraged to open files in a `with` context, to ensure prompt closure.

One thing that my code does not do is capture the error, if any.  It could be wrapped in a `try/except`.  You can even even use `parser.error(your-message)` to display the error in the standard format (with exit).

Anyways, `type` is called with just one argument, a string.  It does not have access to anything else that is going on inside the parser at that time, not even the `args` namespace.  The underlying philosophy of `argparse` is to parse arguments in the order that the user provides.  Positionals are obviously order dependent, but flagged ones (`optionals`) are order independent, so implementing inter-dependencies is awkward.  `multually_exlusive` with an `xor` dependency is the most elaborate it gets.

Other SO questions have asked for inter-dependent `required` or `default` attributes.  Answers have proposed double-parsing or custom `Action` classes, but in my opinion, post-parsing is always simplest.

Double-parsing does have its uses.  For example I wrote the `parser.parse_intermixed_args` method to give more flexibility in mixing positionals and optionals. Fell free to study the `argparse.py` file yourself.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `parse_args()` doesn't know what args need to be loaded. It could be `args.input`, it could be `args.first` and `args.second`, but `args.something_else` shouldn't be, etc.

Comment: If you want to load different sets of arguments, use the subcommand/subparser mechanism.

Comment: It's not that I want to load different sets of arguments in one script. It's that I'm writing dozens of scripts that can have different sets of arguments (each in control of their own argument parser).

Comment: I've ended up agreeing with you that forcing this behavior into `type` is problematic. I'm currently planning on `parse_args(parser, 'name', 'of', 'args', 'which', 'need', 'parsing')`